# Obtain flat list by combining two lists

Tags: python

If I have two lists：`A=[1,2,3]` ,`B=[4,5,6]`.How to combine them like: `C=[1,4,2,5,3,6]`? Is there an effective way to do it, rather than do it like `D=A[0]+B[0]+A[1]+B[1]+A[2]+B[2]`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fastest way to get union of lists - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35866067/fastest-way-to-get-union-of-lists-python)

Answer (score 1):

Use `zip` to aggregate both iterables, and flatten the result with another level of iteration:

```
[i for t in zip(A,B) for i in t]
# [1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd slice.

```
>>> C, C[::2], C[1::2] = A+B, A, B
>>> C
[1, 4, 2, 5, 3, 6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Iterate through the list with a loop:

```
res = []
for i in range(min(len(A), len(B))):
  res.append(A[i])
  res.append(B[i])
```

This stops as soon as one of the lists is out of elements